# Android - After modifying layouts in "Graphical Layout", code changes automatically when scrolled through. How to avoid this?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse with Android layout's main.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163911/eclipse-with-android-layouts-main-xml)

I'm trying to design a layout, statically. I wrote an xml file and I'm, now, modifying it under ***Graphical Layout*** mode. However, when I switch back to the ***XML Editor*** and scroll through the code, the code seems to change automatically. I even tried refreshing the file from ***package explorer*** but still in vain. Now, I know this issue since long but had neglected it. How to avoid such a thing from happening? Thanks.

Comment: There are a million duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my advise is don't do any modification under the **Graphical Layout** only inside the **XML Editor**, the Android support from Graphical Layout is a bit lame , i do all my modification from the **Xml Editor**

Comment: Set Off the option: Preferences | Android | Editors | "Automatically format the XML edited by the visual layout editor" and you should be OK.  With this option OFF and with Juno - the latest version - I don't seem to have this problem anymore with the Graphical Editor but I still do have it with the AndroidManifest.xml file; which use another editor.