# Eclipse(Juno) missing and mixing source when scrolling

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving and vanishing lines of code; trouble with Eclipse's XML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor)

I have dev enviroment setup for Android development.

Problem arises when scrolling. Source code starts to appear with missing parts (like scroll event didn't correctly refresh view). When I select text, it restores it and after deselecting it becomes missing again.

I have dual monitors on win7, but this happens no matter dual display or single display.

Any ideas?

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Does this happen for all file types or only XML ? This may be interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor

Comment: Tnx, that's the thing.I just didn't know what to write find problem like that, tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could potentially be solved by following the steps in this answer : [Moving and vanishing lines of code; trouble with Eclipse's XML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor)

In short "Automatically format the XML edited by the visual layout editor" might be the source of the problem.