# Eclipse hanging when launching android application

Tags: android, eclipse, drivers

I've been having this problem in eclipse whereby my project builds fine, but when I run the application, eclipse hangs and either freezes or throws up a launch error like below

```
[2012-11-02 14:17:31 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've also got this error file [Picture of error file](http://tinypic.com/r/2r5annd/6)

I'm not sure how to pinpoint the source of this problem. I'm using android sdk 4.1.2(APK 16) and android ADT 21 (Preview) on eclipse indigo on a windows 64bit machine. I've also installed the latest available drivers for my device, nexus 7

The same issue occurs whether I try to run on a device or on an emulator so I'm a bit lost as to where to start the troubleshooting...

Comment: I see a similar message as your picture, sometimes when my eclipse doesn't respond and I manually kill the eclipse process via task manager. I would like to see what the answer to this question is.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you use an ADT preview build for development and not a released version? Maybe that's why it's unstable.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem with the last stable version of the ADT.I updated to the ADT preview build due a the XML editing bug raised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor

Comment: @Strokes
have you ever tried it with a completely new Eclipse profile or maybe with the latest Eclipse Juno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to set higher memory limitations in your Eclipse.ini. The actual launch of your application requires more memory due to building the APK, where before that point of time only the Java compiler was involved.

Additionally you may try to work around your problem by starting the AVD manually from the Android AVD manager dialog (which can be reached via one of the toolbar buttons). Then launch your app only after the emulator has been fully started.

Comment: I've changed the Xms value to 512m and the Xmx value to 1024m, it has improved launch performance but I still get a hang about 1 in 4 launches.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this thread, I managed to fix the issue I was experiencing by using one of the USB ports in the back of my computer as oppose to one of the front ones.

Comment: @Strokes This seems to by more to the point in my case as well. Since eclipse doesn't even go anywhere near its max memory during launch, great tip! Btw I also had timeout issues when I used a USB cable that was apparently too long (I think 2 or 3 meters).