# Graphical glitches on Xcode (mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, memory, operating-system

I have this problem for a couple of weeks. I have many graphical glitches, and unwanted views, multiple lines that appears and disappears . I thought that it's just on Xcode but than i saw that it appears also on the browser.

here are some screenshots of the glithes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am now having the exact same problem and it is very frustrating!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet

Comment: What version of OSX you are running?

Answer (score 0):

I would wager that your gpu is artifact sending garbage to you xserver which is being captured by your screen shot software. Then again I would be wrong.

I notice that your issue is real similar to this ::  [Moving and vanishing lines of code; trouble with Eclipse's XML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030727/moving-and-vanishing-lines-of-code-trouble-with-eclipses-xml-editor) Where I noticed `"The reason you get weird visual artifacts is that if a file contains broken DOS line endings (multiple carriage returns without a newline for each carriage return)"`

Now I don't know if you can get teh android team to port their solution up onto a mac but that leaves me with the question, does Select All, Copy, Paste resolve the glitch?